# Why is replacingCharacters necessary for changing the text in text field?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I can change my way to present numbers in the text field using the following line of code based on what I type in the text field. But I can't even type in numbers in the second version of my code.

Why

```
[let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
var newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)]
```

is necessary?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    var newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    var newTextString = String(newText)

    let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    var digitText = ""
    for c in (newTextString?.unicodeScalars)! {
        if digits.contains(UnicodeScalar(c.value)!) {
            digitText.append("\(c)")
        }
    }

    // Format the new string
    if let numOfPennies = Int(digitText) {
        newText = "$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(numOfPennies) + "." + self.centsStringFromInt(numOfPennies)
    } else {
        newText = "$0.00"
    }

    textField.text = newText

    return false
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text!.isEmpty {
        textField.text = "$0.00"
    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true;
}

func dollarStringFromInt(_ value: Int) -> String {
    return String(value / 100)
}

func centsStringFromInt(_ value: Int) -> String {

    let cents = value % 100
    var centsString = String(cents)

    if cents < 10 {
        centsString = "0" + centsString
    }

    return centsString
}
```

If I change it like this, it doesn't work anymore.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var newText = textField.text


    let digits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    var digitText = ""
    for c in (newText?.unicodeScalars)! {
        if digits.contains(UnicodeScalar(c.value)!) {
            digitText.append("\(c)")
        }
    }

    // Format the new string
    if let numOfPennies = Int(digitText) {
        newText = "$" + self.dollarStringFromInt(numOfPennies) + "." + self.centsStringFromInt(numOfPennies)
    } else {
        newText = "$0.00"
    }

    textField.text = newText

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` gets called **before** the text is replaced inside the text field. This method is used for getting the new text before it's accessible with `textField.text`.

If you just want to run logic after the replacement happened, observe the notification called `.UITextFieldTextDidChange`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldTextDidChange), name: .UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: textField)

func textFieldTextDidChange() {
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"shouldChangeCharactersIn" is called BEFORE the text field is modified.  Since your code always returns false, whatever the user has typed in (or pasted in) will not update the field's content unless you do it yourself.

In the second version you are completely ignoring the user's input so your field's value never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets answer by part.

1) The method `replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`isn't required. This methods will replace the substring that matches with range specified. So, according with Apple docs:

> **stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:**
>
> Returns a new string in which the characters in a specified range of the receiver are replaced by a given string

2) The real reason the code change don't work is the return value `false`. Try return `true` and the change will work. Whenever you set the text field `text` property, the method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:` will be invoked (since its delegate is assigned). Returning `false` you are telling the program it should not replace the characters.

**UPDATE**

Try use the UIControl event `Value Changed` as an @IBAction instead `textField:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:` this will work well.

Obs: Sorry for my english

Comment: If the shouldChangeCharactersIn method directly updates the text of the text field, then it must return false.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks do you have any idea why the first version use the .replacingCharacters method to change the text? i mean there are many ways to change the text in the textfield without using that extra line. Is there any benefit using this?

Comment: @willianPoliciano thanks! after changing the return value it works well with the second version. but still got a question see if you can help me with. I address it at the reply to rmaddy

Comment: if false is returned in this method, .UIControl event editingChanged is not raised, as I found out in a hard way